# Canceling factors from numerator and denominator with complex number

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I have the following expression:

$\text{expr} = i \frac{\sqrt{a-b}}{\sqrt{b-a}}x$.

Clearly simplifying expression gives $\text{expr}=x$ by cancelling the numerator and denominator. However, I am not able to perform this simplification in Mathematica. I have tried PowerExpand, Cancel, Factor, FullSimplify and Simplify. Nothing works. Can anyone suggest any method?

Comment: `Simplify[ I Sqrt[a - b] / Sqrt[b - a] x ,  Assumptions -> a > b ]

Comment: Also, note that `Simplify[I Sqrt[a - b]/Sqrt[b - a] x,  Assumptions  ->  a  <  b] ` evaluates to ` - x` which shows that your original conjecture was not generally correct.

Comment: `FunctionDomain` is also works.`I Sqrt[a - b]/Sqrt[b - a] x //  FullSimplify[#, FunctionDomain[I Sqrt[a - b]/Sqrt[b - a] x, {a, b,x}]] &`